# Constructing a Context Free Grammar for checking non-equality of strings

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I have been studying the book *Introduction to Computation* by Michael Sipser on my own, and I'm stuck on this exercise from the chapter on Pushdown Automato and Context-Free Languages. The exercise is to show that  $$A=\{x\#y\,|\, x \neq y\}$$ is a context-free language.

I'm having a hard time proving this because of the second string not reversed. I've tried both making a context-free grammar and a pushdown automata, but in both cases I can't figure out how to make/check that the initial characters of both $x$ and $y$ are the same.

I would appreciate any hints that could help me get to the answer.

Comment: Because you are looking for the non-equality of the two strings you only need to find one position (in both strings) that does not contain equal characters. Can you see how to use non-determinism to do this?

Comment: Oh, I see! Yes, I got it from here, thank you very much!